# How to refactor this to avoid a circular dependency?

Tags: python

I have the following setup:

```
# generator.py
from node import Node

class Generator(object):
  @staticmethod
  def generate(self, node):
     return [Node(), Node(), Node()]

# node.py
from generator import Generator

class Node(object):
   def generate_child_nodes(self):
     self.child_nodes = Generator.generate(self)
```

This over-simplified setup is causing a circular dependency issue.

I generally want the ability of a class to create instances of itself (ex. for mimic-ing a parent child relationship) using a different module (generator.py in this case).

Comment: The ugly and fast way  would be to have  one of the imports as a local import (inside the class or method).

Comment: Alternate approach: Have `generate()` instantiate the respective node class dynamically based on the node instance it already gets passed in? E.g. `return [node.__class__(), node.__class__(), node.__class__()]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
# generator.py

class Generator(object):
  @staticmethod
  def generate(self, node):
     from node import Node
     return [Node(), Node(), Node()]

# node.py
from generator import Generator

class Node(object):
   def generate_child_nodes(self):
     self.child_nodes = Generator.generate(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

generator.py

```
def generate(n):
    for a in range(3):
        yield n()
```

node.py

```
from generator import generate
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id_ = id(self)
for n in generate(Node):
    print(n.id_)
```